# How might I sanitize an XML file before WP Import? (Does wordpress verify or clean text when importing from an XML document? )

Tags: security, bulk-import

I have been tasked to import an older, offline wordpress site. I have the XML export file and a tar-ball of the file tree.

Nothing has given me reason to worry, but does WP check the contents of the XML file as it imports it? Does it attempt to clean anything such as XSS attempts or anything suspicious?

I'm looking to sanitize the entirety of an exported XML from a site that I did not manage or control. The last admin was less then prompt when applying updates. I may be paranoid but I want to ensure the import file is clean before bringing into a server I manage.

Does the community recommend any practice to scan the XML file before input?

Comment: As far as I can see, no.

Answer (score 1):

From quick look at the code the post data mostly goes straight into `wp_insert_post()`, which is a low level function and serves to just store whatever you give it.

If you want to enforce the check you could make use of `wp_import_post_data_raw` filter and probably `wp_kses_post()`.

Comment: In creating code, I'll remember this. Upvote for sure, but